# Adding External URL to JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I need to add a URL to a particular word in JLabel.

For example : 
The JLabel is "Please Click here to report an Issue"

Now my requirement is only work "Click" should work as a link, not complete JLabel.
I tried a work around by whole JLabel is being converted to a link.

```
    String labeltext = "<html><font color='black'>This is where you can log your time activity for the presales process. We are constantly " +
            "upgrading our presales tools, <br /> so if you have any feedback, please click <a href='#' style='color: blue;'>here</a> to send us the request.</font></html>";
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(labeltext);

    lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try {
                URI uri = new URI("10.5.44.108/issue.html");
                desktop.browse(uri);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Kindly let me know if anyone has any suggestion to achieve this.

Thanks in advance !!

Best Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: *""Please Click here to report an Issue""* 1) The user would select **here** rather than **Click**.  2) This is not a GUI (using a `JLabel`) suited to use via keyboard - a major detriment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to embed html component inside you java app, have a look at [JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).
Here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).